# var in protocol as specific protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

How to describe a variable in a protocol on swift
any type, but supports a specific protocol

Something like this

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    var itemsList: AnyObject where Collection { get } // AnyObject supports a Collection protocol
}
```

Comment: `var itemsList: Collection { get set }`?

Comment: it give error: Protocol 'Collection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: Post the full declaration of your `Collection` protocol.

Comment: @JAL I assume he's referring to the stdlib `Collection` protocol?

Comment: @Hamish ... my bad.

Comment: Can you use an associated type? You may still get the same error but not sure. In the protocol add `associatedtype T: Collection` and then `itemsList: T`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want:

```
protocol MyProtocol: class {
    associatedtype T: Collection
    var itemsList: T { get }
}
```

If you want `T` to definitely be an object as well (not a `struct`) then you must wait for [this proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md) to make it into the language.

If you want a class to satisfy this protocol with `T` unspecified in the class's definition, make the class generic.

```
class C<T: Collection>: MyProtocol {
    let itemsList: T

    init(_ itemsList: T) {
        self.itemsList = itemsList
    }
}

let x = C([1,2,3])
```

Comment: thanks, and is it possible to describe this in one line?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Although note that this doesn't constrain `T` to `AnyObject` – you'd want `associatedtype T: Collection, AnyObject` for that. Also note that this isn't quite the same as what OP was proposing (assuming I understood correctly) – this allows conforming types to satisfy the associated type with a *single* concrete type that conforms to `Collection`, rather than allowing for conforming types to have an `itemsList` property that deals with *any* type that conforms to the protocol(s). For that, you'd need a type eraser (or just use the sdlib's `AnyCollection` if `AnyObject` isn't a constraint).

Comment: @BallpointBen That's still homogeneous, just per-instance rather than per-conforming type. An instance of `C` cannot allow any given type that conforms `Collection` to be assigned to `itemsList`, only a single concrete type. Although by the fact that OP has accepted your answer, I assume homogeneous is what he/she wants. I was just pointing out that the question sounded like it was asking for a heterogeneous typed property, which would have to be achieved with a type eraser :)